# Форматирование числа с точкой вместо запятой

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть: текст бокс для ввода чисел с дробной частью и простой код

```
txb_Count.Text = Count.ToString("0.00");
```

В результате которого получается число вида -12,00 - т.е. с запятой. В то же время в БД (Mysql) эти числа хранятся в Decimal(10,2) и запятую в качестве разделителя не принимает - только точку.

Вопрос: есть ли простой способ изменить `ToString("0.00")` что бы при форматировании отображалась точка а не запятая? Пробовал `ToString("F")`, `ToString("E")`  - возвращает ','.

Comment: Так от локали ведь зависит.

Comment: @klutch1991 "Incorrect decimal value '250,55'". Не хочется писать цикл с перебором.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формат вывода строки зависит от локали, установленной на конечной машине, на которой выполняется Ваш код, если вы явно не указываете экземпляр `IFormatProvider`.
Скорее всего на Вашей машине локаль - "ru-RU", которая неявно вызывается при форматировании значения и выводе на экран. Для того, чтобы отображалась точка, можете явно указать американскую локаль ("en-US") для форматирования.
Код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

`txb_Count.Text = Count.ToString("0.00",
                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));`

Если хотите изменить значение для всей сборки, и не указывать локаль явно при каждом вызове `ToString()`, то можете использовать такой вариант:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Затем:

```
txb_Count.Text = Count.ToString("0.00");
```

Соответственно строка кода с присвоением нового значения свойству `CurrentCulture` должна быть написана раньше любого вызова метода `ToString()`. Например в методе инициализации, или в каком-нибудь статическом конструкторе.

Если проблема с формированием SQL-запроса на сохранение данных, и Вы действительно формируете запрос путём конкатенации строк, в результате чего и получаете исключение, то запрос следует формировать следующим образом:

```
var query = String.Format("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES({0})", myDecimal.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```

Comment: А можно как то указать IFormatProvider для всей сборки и не прописывать для каждой форматируемой строчки?

Comment: Теперь FormatException вылетает и число знаков после запятой неограниченно.

Comment: Вылетает в каком случае?

Comment: Лучше бы ты обратил внимание на фразу _"В то же время в БД ... запятую в качестве разделителя не принимает - только точку"_ ;)

Comment: Так проблема с выводом данных, или с сохранением в БД?

Comment: С сохранением : `ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect decimal value: '120000,90' for column`  с точкой нет проблем. Точнее мне нужно и получать данные из базы и сохранять. Все в Decimal

Comment: @klutch1991 `error CS0200: Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' -- доступ только для чтения`

Comment: @klutch1991, т. е. ты ещё не догадался, что он sql-запрос конкатенацией собирает?

Comment: Нет :) А какая  версия фреймворка? Странно, что "'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' -- доступ только для чтения"

Comment: Так в чём проблема, при конкатенации, форматируйте строку так, чтобы выводилась точка вместо запятой

Comment: `var query = String.Format("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES({0})", myDecimal.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));`